# Unable to ping google from inside ubuntu docker container

Tags: docker, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, vagrantfile

I'm completely new to docker and linux and I'm trying to ping google from within a docker container. I'm getting the following error....

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ docker run ubuntu ping google.com
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"ping\":
executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

As inferred above, I'm using the [ubuntu/trusty64 box](https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64) on vagrant.

I've enabled a public network in my vagrantfile

```
  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  config.vm.network "public_network"
```

And can ping google from the VM

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.204.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr25s12-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.204.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=29.5 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s12-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.204.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=36.2 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s12-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.204.46): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=95.7 ms
```

But not within the docker container it seems.

I tried this solution but it didn't help - https://odino.org/cannot-connect-to-the-internet-from-your-docker-containers/

What could be the problem here?

Thanks,

Comment: Those down votes are not mine, but would like to know, why are you doing "docker run ping.."??  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ Will tell you about docker run. Also, you need to specify what exactly you are trying to achieve  as I can see vagrant also has been tagged

Comment: The question clearly explains what I'm trying to achieve - I would like to be able to ping google from inside a docker container and thus confirm an internet connection. I've tried variations on the docker run command such as `docker run -ti ubuntu ping google.com` and `docker run --rm ubuntu ping google.com` both with the same result as described in the question. 

Why has this been downvoted? I'm following a tutorial on Packt that uses the exact commands above. As a beginner it's pretty much impossible to get a question with positive upvotes on this site.

Comment: I only wanted to know, why are you using vagrant and Docker both if you are a beginner? Instead, please follow Docker quick start guide. Also, you haven't mentioned your host OS. If you could mention that, one can guide you in right direction.

Comment: Whats wrong with trying to use vagrant and docker as a beginner? My host OS is windows and I would like to use docker with linux so this seems like a perfectly reasonable approach to take. I would also like to get more familiar with the linux terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is telling you the "ping" command is not included in the ubuntu base image. Docker images are stripped down and you need to install whatever applications you'd like to run in them. If you run the container with /bin/bash, you can install ping in that container with:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install iputils-ping
```

You can find ping and a lot of other networking tools preinstalled in `nicolaka/netshoot` which I like for network troubleshooting:

```
docker run -it --rm nicolaka/netshoot ping www.google.com
```

Comment: I have no internet access when using `docker run -it ubuntu`